# Statistically Analyzing Numerical Rating Scale

Tags: ordinal-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, likert, scales

I'm creating a survey to administer to food inspectors n=30 for an internship project. I want to find their opinions related to food truck and restaurant food poisoning topics and see if their opinions differ by establishment type. I've created a survey with 5 questions, each question has a numerical rating scale for each type of food establishment. Below is a made up example of one question, there will be 4 more.

[image: Example Question]

I would like to find a way to statistically analyze my findings. One solution I thought of was having a **food truck vector** = (all food truck answers) and a **restaurant vector** = (all restaurant answers), and conduct a Mann-Whitney Test since I can't conduct a independent sample t-test. From what I'm aware of Mann-Whitney tests difference in medians instead of means.

Does this sound good? Or does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: Mann Whintey *only* tests median (and mean) difference with two stringent additional assumptions: (i) distributions are identically shaped, and (ii) distributions have identical variance. More generally and less restrictively, this is a test of $H_{0}$: $P(X_{A}>X_{B}) = 0.5$ with $H_{A}$: $P(X_{A}>X_{B}) \ne 0.5$. In plain language, it's a test of the null that a random observation from group $A$ has an equal probability of being greater than or less than a random observation from group $B$.

Comment: Need some details to make sense of your design. How many subjects in truck category and how many in restaurant? For each subject, how many questions with 1-10 answers. Might help if you said _exactly_ why you can't use t test for 2 indep samples. (Not normal? Not independent?)

Comment: So all 30 food inspectors will complete the survey which consists of 5 questions similar to the one I shared. For each question they will choose a value 0-10 for Food Trucks and also a value for 0-10 for Restaurants. In the end I'll have ten 0-10 values chosen per survey respondent. I would like to do analysis to see if there is a significant difference between their perceptions on food poisoning risk factors between Food Trucks and Restaurants.

Comment: @Alexis the book I'm referencing says that "the Mann-Whitney test does not require homogeneity of variance or normal distributions" and that only "the U-test does require independent observations"

Comment: @RyanDoherty I never said the Mann-Whitney test requires homogeneity of variance (reread my comment closely), and I wrote *nothing* about normality. Are you sure you are directing your comment in the correct conversation? In [Mann & Whitney's 1947 paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177730491), they are *explicit* that theirs is a test of relative stochastic size as I have indicated… in fact it's in the title of their paper.

Comment: @Alexis but doesn't "identical variance" and "homogeneity of variance" mean the same thing?

Comment: @RyanDoherty Sure. I am still pretty sure I said that the test **only** requires these additional assumptions when testing for median or mean difference (not when testing for evidence that one sample is stochastically larger than the other).